# Why does nuxeo ask to register the instance?

Tags: nuxeo

Nuxeo is open source but when we download Nuxeo it does not start untill we register. Registering is valid only for 30 day trial license. Could you please let us know how we can use the open source Nuxeo?

Comment: "It does not start" is not enough to diagnose what's happening. What are the exact messages or errors you have?

Comment: Question is not about errors, how can we use open source version as registration is mandatory ?

Comment: Registration is not mandatory in Nuxeo, which _is_ open source, so you must be mistaken somewhere. That's why I'm asking about exact errors or messages about registration you see, to understand what you're using.

Answer (score 2):

The registration is only needed for [the support service](https://www.nuxeo.com/services/#support). It allows to install some restricted packages such as the maintenance hotfixes.

You can unregister your instance (`rm nxserver/data/instance.clid`) and it will continue to work fine without the Nuxeo support and maintenance. Without the benefit of this charged service, you may prefer to use FastTrack than LTS releases: see [the Nuxeo Release Cycle](https://doc.nuxeo.com/nuxeo-release-cycle/).

Comment: Hi Julien, I also noticed we cannot install plugin via nuxeoctl untill the instance is registered. Is there any clear separation on what is Open source & what is licensed?

Answer (score 1):

If at startup you have a message like `NUXEO INSTANCE REGISTRATION HAS EXPIRED` then you're not using the open source version of Nuxeo, you're using a version containing additional hotfixes that come from the Trial version of the [Nuxeo Online Services](https://www.nuxeo.com/services/#support), and which can't be used after the trial expires without a support contract.

You're always free to download the full released version (https://www.nuxeo.com/downloads/) or compile Nuxeo from source (https://doc.nuxeo.com/corg/compiling-nuxeo-from-sources/).